# How to implement in an android application Navigation Drawer + the brand-new Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I've started to develop an android application, which consist of the following:

- MainActivity: extends FragmentActivity.
- Several fragments: extending android.support.v4.app.Fragment each one.

MainActivity starts with the application and it has an ActionBarDrawer (it was a requirement of the client to implement a drawer-like menu). Besides, MainActivity makes fragment transaction: when X option within the drawer is clicked, MainActivity replaces and sets the desired Fragment (a default fragment is set when the application starts).

This picture ilustrates it:
[image: screenshoot of my application, with the drawer opened]

My classes:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
// that is the one which is deprecated: ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle:
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mDrawerMenuTitles;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...


public class FragmentEuskalmet extends Fragment implements    android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
```

activity_main.xml layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

drawer_list_item.xml layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

I've realised that with the release of Android 5.0, ActionBar has been deprecated. So my question is the following: how to change my application to support the new Toolbar, using its new navigation drawer (replacing the deprecated one) and maintaining my Fragment usage within the MainActivity (using FragmentActivity)?

Thanks in advance for your appreciated help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ActionBar **is not deprecated** in Android 5.0.

Beginning with Android 5.0 (API level 21), the action bar **may be represented by any Toolbar** widget within the application layout.

Said that, to replace the ActionBar with the new Toolbar and the new `appcompat v21` you have to:

- extend the `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity`
- use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` when you need
- use a theme which inherits from *Theme.AppCompat*.(for example Light or NoActionBar)
- put the *Toolbar* view inside your layout

More info [here:](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Then to integrate the navDrawer you can do:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mDrawerToggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,mToolbar, R.string.app_name,    
      R.string.app_name);
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Comment: I've used the following site http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/ 's guide to adapt my code and it works! His GitHub repo with the suggested project is here:  https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere